# New version of django-model-utils doesn't have PassThroughManager

Tags: python, django, database, model, django-queryset

I use Django 1.9.9 So how can I edit my model instead of PassThroughManager?

```
from model_utils.managers import PassThroughManager

class TopicQuerySet(QuerySet):

    def get_topic_today(self):
        return self.filter(created_at__day=datetime.date.today()).order_by('title')

    def get_topic_popular(self):
        return self.annotate(entry_count=Count('entry')).order_by('-entry_count')


class Topic(TimeStampModel):

    objects = PassThroughManager.for_queryset_class(TopicQuerySet)()
```

Should I try to use [GeoManager](http://django-model-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/managers.html#passthroughmanager)?

Answer (score 3):

Newer versions of Django (1.9+ I believe) have some built-in (*model_utils*) **PassThroughManager** like functionality. Rewrite like this and you should get the same concept:

```python
from django.db.models import Manager
from django.db.models.query import QuerySet

class TopicManager(Manager):
    pass

class TopicQuerySet(QuerySet):

    def get_topic_today(self):
        return self.filter(created_at__day=datetime.date.today()).order_by('title')

    def get_topic_popular(self):
        return self.annotate(entry_count=Count('entry')).order_by('-entry_count')

class Topic(TimeStampModel):
    objects = TopicManager.from_queryset(TopicQuerySet)()
```